# Error: reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type CLLocation at locations.0

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to save `let myLocations[CLLocation]` to Firebase, but getting an error:

> reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type CLLocation at locations.0. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.

Any help?

Code:

```
var myLocations: [CLLocation] = []

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        myLocations.append(locations[0] as CLLocation)

        let spanX = 0.007
        let spanY = 0.007

        var location = CLLocation()
        for L in myLocations {
            location = L
        }
        let newRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(spanX, spanY))
        theMap.setRegion(newRegion, animated: true)

        if (myLocations.count > 3){
            let sourceIndex = myLocations.count - 1
            let destinationIndex = myLocations.count - 4
            let c1 = myLocations[sourceIndex].coordinate
            let c2 = myLocations[destinationIndex].coordinate
            var a = [c1, c2]
            let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &a, count: a.count)
            polyline.title = "polyline"
            theMap.add(polyline)
        }

        if startLocation == nil {
            startLocation = locations.first as CLLocation!
        } else {
            let lastDistance = lastLocation.distance(from: locations.last as CLLocation!) //In Meter
            distanceTraveled += lastDistance * 0.000621371192 //In Miles
            //1 Meter = 0.000621371192 Miles
            //1 Mile = 1609.344 Meters
            distanceLabel_String = String(format: "%.2f  mi", distanceTraveled)
            distanceLabel.text = distanceLabel_String
            let altitude = lastLocation.altitude // In Meters
            let altitudeInFeets = altitude / 0.3048 //In Feets
            arrayOfAltitude.append(altitudeInFeets)
            let maxAltitude = arrayOfAltitude.max()
            altitudeLabel_String = String(format: "%.2f ft", maxAltitude!)
            altitudeLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f ft", altitudeInFeets)
        }

        lastLocation = locations.last as CLLocation!

    }




func saveLocations() {

    let locations = myLocations

    let trailInfo: Dictionary<String, Any> = [ "locations" : locations,]


        let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        databaseRef.child("Trails").childByAutoId().setValue(trailInfo)
    }

@IBAction func doneActivityHit(_ sender: UIButton) {
    saveLocations()
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    myLocations.removeAll()
    distanceTraveled = 0
}
```

Comment: Show. Your. Code.

Comment: I have added pieces of code

Comment: You need to store it in a format `NSNumber`, `NSString`, `NSDictionary`, and `NSArray`. Save in `[{"longitude":xxxx, "latitude":xxxx}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your error message is clear:

> reason: '(setValue:) Cannot store object of type CLLocation at locations.0. Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.

The [docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/Firebase.html#//api/name/setValue:) on `setValue:` say the same thing:

> Data types that can be set are:
>
> NSString – @“Hello World”
>
> NSNumber (also includes boolean) – @YES,
>   @43, @4.333
>
> NSDictionary – @{@“key”: @“value”, @“nested”:
>   @{@“another”: @“value”} }
>
> NSArray

CLLocation isn't any of those. You cannot store a CLLocation using `setValue`.

The usual thing is to split each CLLocation up into its latitude and longitude, which are numbers (notice that NSNumber appears in the list), and express the whole thing as a dictionary (notice that NSDictionary appears in the list). So, given a location `theLocation`, you would say:

```
let dict = ["Latitude": theLocation.coordinate.latitude, "Longitude": theLocation.coordinate.longitude]
```

You can do that for each location you wish to store (and reverse the process to retrieve and reconstruct the location).

Comment: I understand this "You cannot store a CLLocation using setValue".  any solution?

Comment: Read the edited answer... Whoever downvoted this is just an idiot, ignore them.